# Google Prediction max CSV size?

Tags: machine-learning, google-prediction

I uploading a 1.8Gb CSV file on Google Cloud Storage.

When I start the training from the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/prediction/v1.6/prediction.trainedmodels.insert) I get an error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Data size limit exceeded."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Data size limit exceeded."
 }
}
```

I'm confusing. [From the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/faq) I can read:

> **What training data does the Prediction API support?**
>   Training data can be provided in one of three ways:
>   A CSV formatted training data file up to 2.5GB in size, loaded into Google Storage.

And from the [pricing page](https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/pricing):

> **Training:**
>   $0.002/MB bulk trained (maximum size of each dataset: 250MB)

What is the difference from this 250MB and the 2.5GB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a small bug in the Google Prediction API.

I posted the question on Google Group and the team fixed the bug pretty quickly:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/prediction-api-discuss/Ap0WbdTco2g/kHoEMbJPteYJ

Answer (score 0):

If you are using for free then

```
Training: 5MB trained/day
```

and if you are using paid version then

```
$0.002/MB bulk trained (maximum size of each dataset: 2.5GB)
```

The pricing page link which you have sent shows me 2.5 GB.

You seems to be using version 1.5 which has 250 mb of limit, version 1.6 has 2.5gb